# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysema/query/types/Predicate

Tags: spring, postgresql

I am getting this exception while running tomcat server(8.0 ver).
And I am using **postgresql** to connect my **spring mvc** project with db.

Answer (score 0):

There's two different groupIds for queryDSL. Make sure that in your dependency section (pom.xml/build.gradle) you use the own that reads `com.querydsl`, not `com.mysema`, as it is basically incompatible with Spring.

Example:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```